# What is Dynamic Linq Query in dotnet core?

Tags: linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am working with EF(Dotnet Core) and I need to call data on the basis of Input parameter that is not constant, how can I use if my UI like this, someone told me for doing this kind of work I need to know Dynamic Linq Query.
I need theoretically idea so I can Proceed work for the given situations.

[image: My Condition Image]

Comment: EF is not really build for this and I think you would be much better off saving everything as key/value pairs or something else where the schema remains static.